# Why does my computer run slower on ubuntu than on Windows?

Tags: graphics, performance

I recently installed Ubuntu and am multi-booting with Windows 7, but I would like to switch over to Linux full time. Now I am seeing that it runs a lot slower; I have a few examples:

I've tried playing Euro truck Simulator 2 and now I can't even run it when before it would run fine on max settings, also when I open up a web browser it takes forever to load up. I do have 8GB of RAM and 3.6GHz CPU, so I don't think that that is the problem.

I'm quite new to Ubuntu so i could just be something stupid, but this is a problem.

Comment: Is there anything listed in Software Sources > Additional Drivers tab?

Comment: I don't think there's a Euro truck simulator for native Ubuntu. I think it's wine only, and in that case it might be slower. But have you installed the graphic drivers for your card? check the comment above..

Comment: Euro Trucksim 2 does have a linux version

Comment: You still haven't answered us if you have your graphic card driver installed, check software sources --> additional drivers..

Comment: I apologize, yes i do have the drivers for my card installed

Comment: Are you using `radeon ` driver or `fglrx` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a matter of whether your CPU and/or GPU is better optimized on Windows or Linux kernel you are using. In addition, there may be performance differences b/w Windows and Ubuntu on the device drivers with your peripherals or GPU.  Manufacturers usually provide-optimized device drivers to Windows (e.g., Nvidia).

Answer (score -1):

Is it a laptop or a stationary system? I've seen weird laptop configurations where your cpu will scale up but not enough to trigger the underlying system to increase it's performance.  To see if that's the issue do sudo apt-get install turbostat && sudo modprobe msr && sudo turbostat. Use the system for a bit and look at the ghz column, it should scale up to what you expect (including turbo boost).

What's more likely though is that it's a GPU issue. What kind of GPU do you have in the system?

Comment: I've got a desktop tower, also my graphics card is a radeon hd 7770